# Printing max values

Tags: java

This is my source code:

```
public class Fibbonaci {

static int count;
static int size;

public static int Fibbonaci(int n) {
    count++;

    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n % 10 == 0) {
        return (Fibbonaci(n / 2) + Fibbonaci(n / 5));
    } else if (n % 6 == 0) {
        return (Fibbonaci(n / 2) + Fibbonaci(n / 3));
    } else {
        return (Fibbonaci(n / 3) + Fibbonaci(n / 5));
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] lim = new int[1024];

    for (int n = 1; n <= lim.length - 1; n++) {
        count = 0;
        Fibbonaci(n);
        size = (int) Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)) + 1;

        System.out.print("T(" + size + ") = ");
        System.out.println("" + count);
    }
}
```

}

Some of my current output is this:

```
T(1) = 3
T(2) = 3
T(2) = 5
T(3) = 5
T(3) = 7
T(3) = 9
T(3) = 7
T(4) = 7
T(4) = 9
T(4) = 11
T(4) = 9
T(4) = 15
```

How can i print the max value for the size and count where i can get an output of similar to T(1) = 3 T(2) = 5 T(3) = 9 T(4) = 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the list of values for each size (in a `Map` preferably), sort this list and print the biggest element.

**EDIT** Even simpler - overwrite the value for each size in a `Map<Integer, Integer>` and as the latest result is the biggest, the last value in the `Map` is the biggest for this size.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the max value in a variable and compare it inside your loop

```
maxValue = 0;
if ( X > maxValue ){
    maxValue = X
}
```

Also, you could use a collection and order it, use comparators. But just so you know, there are much better implementations for Fibonacci (just google for it)

Using list to order: [how to get maximum value from the List/ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304767/how-to-get-maximum-value-from-the-list-arraylist)

Using comparators http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html