# Trying to find max element in ArrayList<Float>, in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, max

I have an ArrayList with Float elements in Java, and I am trying to find the position of the element with the maximum value.
I tried to do this with the following code but it didn't work:

```
 Float obj = Collections.max(arraylist);
    int index=arraylist.indexOf(obj);
```

The problem is that `Collections.max()`, which seems to work for int values, returns a wrong result in my case..

Any ideas on what is going wrong and how can I do this differently?

Correction: The problem is not where I thought, it is when adding the elements to the Arraylist. The values that I add are the float results of a function. I print the result of the function right before I add it, then I use the usual `arraylist.add(value)` code, but when I ask to print the value of the arraylist right after its addition, a completely different one is returned :/

Comment: What is the result you get and the expected one?

Comment: Create a simple use case for which it does not work and post it here.

Comment: Which values do `obj` and `index` have?

Comment: What is the declared type of `arraylist`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way for get min and max value from a list of Comparables in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369383/best-way-for-get-min-and-max-value-from-a-list-of-comparables-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I found it guys!
The problem was that instead of storing the result of the function in a float value and then using it, I called the function everytime I wanted the value in order to save memory space.
I had forgotten to initialize one value of the function though, so everytime it gave me a different start-value, so everytime I called the function it returned a different result..

Thank you very much for your help, it may have taken me much longer to find it without your questions which led my thought to the real problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**IndexOf** returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element, and NOT the maximum you're looking for.

check documentation here http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

You also have to specify the type of the elements stored on the ArrayList. Try :

```
... new ArrayList<Float>() ; ..
```

Comment: As a matter of fact it should return the index of the `max_element` which was found with `Collection.max()`

Comment: @alji-mohamed Yes, but `Collections.max()` does (or at least should) return the maximum, depending on the `Comparable` implementation.

Comment: I think he defines ArrayList< **Float** >() with int rather than Float. please check !

Comment: @ALJIMohamed what do you mean with "_ArrayList< Float >() with int_"?

Comment: `ArrayList<int>()` that means the ArrayList is supposed to store ints. If you put Floats on it, it will be rounded down (or up) !

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have both the following libraries added...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
```

can you try this code? Instead of saving to a Float object,

```
Object obj = Collections.max(arrayList);
```

Comment: Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304767/how-to-get-maximum-value-from-the-list-arraylist)

Comment: Yes, I do have the libraries added.
I tried to change it to Object but still didn't worked properly :S