# Getting max from LinkedList

Tags: java

I'm making an application where the user can save travels with destination and length of travel. Then I somehow want to see what the longest are. All travels are objects in a LinkedList, and length of travel is integer.

How can I get the highest value of length of travel?

**Solution:** Ended up using iteration through nodes:

```
for (Travel travel : travelList) {
longest = travel.getLength();
destination = travel.getDest();
if (travel.getLength() >= longest)
{
    destination = travel.getDest();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I have tried Collections.max(MyTravelList), but without any luck. Got an error. I guess that it sort list in total, and not only by length.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection) , also check Comparable, these are the tools you need... try yourself you should be able to get it. Also this previous post will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369383/best-way-for-get-min-and-max-value-from-a-list-of-comparables-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider iteration over each node of LinkedList to find out longest destination.

Comment: Actually, this will be working. Saving node in variable if highest. It seems this is easier to do than using a Comparator. But which is best, and why?

Comment: There is no much difference, take a look at source code of Collection.max method. It does the same things and it requires N iteration. Probably, you can find max method more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing travels using your own java object, then here's the pointer. Look at Collections.max () and Comparator and Comparable interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [`public static <T> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

You need to create a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for you object first, and supply an instance of the comparator while calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your Travel class so that it implements Comparable interface, and add something like.-

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Travel another) {
    return getLength().compareTo(another.getLength());
}
```

Then you can call

`Collections.sort(travelsList);`

to sort the list using your compare criteria defined in `compareTo` method